# ASP.NET MVC - share master pages between applications?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, master-pages, share

I have two MVC 2 apps configured in IIS as:

> /mysite
>
> /mysite/admin

The root application contains some master pages, etc that I'd like to share between the applications. ASP.NET is, of course, giving me the error message:

> Parser Error Description: An error
> occurred during the parsing of a
> resource required to service this
> request. Please review the following
> specific parse error details and
> modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: The virtual path
> '/Views/Shared/SiteCenterLayout.Master'
> maps to another application, which is
> not allowed.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ Master Language="C#"
> MasterPageFile="/Views/Shared/SiteCenterLayout.Master"
> AutoEventWireup="true"
> Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage"
> %>

Any suggestions? I could probably create a virtual directory on the /admin application to point to the root's /views/shared folder,  but it'd be nice not to have to do that as it seems a bit of a hack.